# Boost::asio asynchronous calls not working properly

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

When I run the following test,

```
TEST_CASE("DummyNetwork_Basic") {
    // start a network at port 3000
    DummyNetwork network3000 = DummyNetwork(3000);
    network3000.listenForIncomingConnections();

    // start a network at port 3001
    DummyNetwork network3001 = DummyNetwork(3001);
    network3001.listenForIncomingConnections();

    // network 3001 connects to network 3000
    network3001.connect(3000);

    // sleep to give time for connection
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(50));

    // network 3000 sends message to network 3001
    network3000.send(3001, NetworkMessage{1, "hi"});

    // network 3001 calls a blocking function to receive messages
    NetworkMessage receivedOnN2_m1 = network3001.receiveMessageWithTypes(std::vector<int>{1}, 3000);

    bool result1 = receivedOnN2_m1.encodedData_ == "hi";
            CHECK(result1);

    // network 3001 sends messages to network 3000
    network3001.send(3000, NetworkMessage{2, "hello"});
    network3001.send(3000, NetworkMessage{1, "hii"});

    // network 3000 attempts to receive messages via blocking read
    NetworkMessage receivedOnN1_m1 = network3000.receiveMessageWithTypes(std::vector<int>{2}, 3001);
    NetworkMessage receivedOnN1_m2 = network3000.receiveMessageWithTypes(std::vector<int>{1}, 3001);

    // clean up
    network3000.shutdown();
    network3001.shutdown();

    bool result2 = receivedOnN1_m1.encodedData_ == "hello";
    bool result3 = receivedOnN1_m2.encodedData_ == "hii";
            CHECK(result2);
            CHECK(result3);

    if (result1 && result2 && result3) {
        std::cout << "DummyNetwork_Basic Passed" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "DummyNetwork_Basic Passed" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

It fails. In fact, the only output I see (which will later make sense) is

```
DummyNetwork3000: Created
DummyNetwork3000: Listening at port3000
DummyNetwork3001: Created
DummyNetwork3001: Listening at port3001
*thread sleeps to give time for connection*
DummyNetwork3000: Can't send. Not connected to port3001
```

Here is the header file for DummyNetwork.

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include "NetworkMessage.hpp"

class DMessageReceival {
public:
    DMessageReceival(NetworkMessage message, std::string sender);
    NetworkMessage message_;
    std::string sender_;
};


class DConnection {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;
    std::string otherPort_;
    std::string otherName_;
    std::atomic<bool> disconnectRequested_{false};

    DConnection(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, std::string otherPort, std::string otherName);
};

class DummyNetwork {
public:
    DummyNetwork(int port);
    void listenForIncomingConnections();
    void send(int port, const NetworkMessage& msg);
    void connect(int port);
    void disconnect(int port);
    NetworkMessage receiveMessageWithTypes(const std::vector<int>& types, int port = 0);
    void shutdown();

private:
    int port_;
    boost::asio::io_service ioService_;
    boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<DConnection>> connections_;
    boost::unordered_map<int, std::vector<DMessageReceival>> messages_;

    std::atomic<bool> isListening_{false};
    std::atomic<bool> shutdownRequested_{false};
    std::condition_variable messagesConditionVariable_;
    std::mutex connectionsMutex_;
    std::mutex messagesMutex_;

    void printDebugMessage(std::string input);
    bool isConnected(int name);
    void handleAccept(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, const boost::system::error_code& error);
    void handleHandshakeRead(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, std::string buffer, const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_read);
    void handleRead(std::shared_ptr<DConnection> connection, std::string buffer, const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_read);
    void handleWrite(const boost::system::error_code& error, const NetworkMessage& msg, std::string other_name);
    void handleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, std::string name);
    void handleHandshakeWrite(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::shared_ptr<DConnection> conn);
};
```

Here is the Implementation

```
#include "../include/DummyNetwork.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>



DMessageReceival::DMessageReceival(NetworkMessage message, std::string sender) {
    message_ = message;
    sender_ = sender;
}

DConnection::DConnection(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, std::string otherPort, std::string otherName) {
    socket_ = socket;
    otherPort_ = otherPort;
    otherName_ = otherName;
}

void DummyNetwork::printDebugMessage(std::string input) {
    std::cout << "DummyNetwork" << std::to_string(port_) << ": " << input << std::endl;
}

DummyNetwork::DummyNetwork(int port) : port_(port), ioService_() {
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(ioService_);
    std::thread ioServiceThread([this]() {
        ioService_.run();
    });
    ioServiceThread.detach();
    printDebugMessage("Created");
}

void DummyNetwork::listenForIncomingConnections() {
    if (!isListening_.exchange(true)) {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port_);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ioService_, endpoint);
        std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(ioService_));
        printDebugMessage("Listening at port" + std::to_string(port_));
        acceptor.async_accept(*socket, boost::bind(&DummyNetwork::handleAccept, this, socket,
                                                       boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
}

bool DummyNetwork::isConnected(int name) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(connectionsMutex_);
    const auto it = connections_.find(std::to_string(name));
    if (it != connections_.end()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void DummyNetwork::handleHandshakeRead(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, std::string buffer, const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_read) {
    NetworkMessage msg = NetworkMessage::decode(buffer);
    if (msg.type_ == 0 && !isConnected(std::stoi(msg.encodedData_))) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(connectionsMutex_);
        std::string other_port = std::to_string(socket->remote_endpoint().port());
        std::shared_ptr<DConnection> conn = std::make_shared<DConnection>(socket, other_port, msg.encodedData_);
        connections_[conn->otherName_] = conn;
        printDebugMessage("Resolved port" + conn->otherPort_ + "to be port" + conn->otherName_);
        char new_buffer[10000];
        socket->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(new_buffer),
                                boost::bind(&DummyNetwork::handleRead, this, conn, new_buffer,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}

void DummyNetwork::handleRead(std::shared_ptr<DConnection> connection, std::string buffer, const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_read) {
    NetworkMessage msg = NetworkMessage::decode(buffer);
    if (msg.type_ != 0 && !shutdownRequested_ && !connection->disconnectRequested_ && connection->socket_->is_open()) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(messagesMutex_);
        messages_[msg.type_].push_back(DMessageReceival(msg, connection->otherName_));
        messages_[0].push_back(DMessageReceival(msg, connection->otherName_));
        printDebugMessage("Received " + msg.encodedData_ + " from " + connection->otherName_);
        messagesConditionVariable_.notify_all();
        char new_buffer[10000];
        connection->socket_->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(new_buffer),
                                boost::bind(&DummyNetwork::handleRead, this, connection, new_buffer,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}

void DummyNetwork::handleAccept(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket,
                                const boost::system::error_code& error) {
    isListening_ = false;
    printDebugMessage("Accepted connection to port" + socket->remote_endpoint().port());
    char buffer[10000];
    socket->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
                            boost::bind(&DummyNetwork::handleHandshakeRead, this, socket, buffer,
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    listenForIncomingConnections();
}

void DummyNetwork::send(int port, const NetworkMessage& msg) {
    if (!shutdownRequested_ && !isConnected(port)) {
        printDebugMessage("Can't send. Not connected to port" + std::to_string(port));
    }
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(connectionsMutex_);
    std::shared_ptr<DConnection> conn = connections_[std::to_string(port)];
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket = conn->socket_;
    socket->async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(msg.encode(),msg.encode().length()),
                             boost::bind(&DummyNetwork::handleWrite, this,boost::asio::placeholders::error, msg, conn->otherName_));
    printDebugMessage("Requested to write msg " + msg.encodedData_ + " to port" + std::to_string(port));
}

void DummyNetwork::handleWrite(const boost::system::error_code& error, const NetworkMessage& msg, std::string other_name) {
    printDebugMessage("Wrote " + msg.encodedData_ + " to " + other_name);
}

void DummyNetwork::handleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, std::string name) {
    if (!shutdownRequested_) {
        printDebugMessage("Can't connect. Shutdown");
    }
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(connectionsMutex_);
    std::shared_ptr<DConnection> conn = std::make_shared<DConnection>(socket, name, name);
    connections_[conn->otherName_] = conn;
    NetworkMessage msg = NetworkMessage{0, std::to_string(port_)};
    socket->async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(msg.encode(),msg.encode().length()),
                             boost::bind(&DummyNetwork::handleHandshakeWrite, this,boost::asio::placeholders::error, conn));
}

void DummyNetwork::handleHandshakeWrite(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::shared_ptr<DConnection> conn) {
    printDebugMessage("Connected to port" + conn->otherName_);
}

void DummyNetwork::connect(int name) {
    if (isConnected(name)) {
        return;
    }
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioService_);
    auto new_socket = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(ioService_);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("127.0.0.1", std::to_string(name));
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
    new_socket->async_connect(endpoint,
                          boost::bind(&DummyNetwork::handleConnect, this,
                                      boost::asio::placeholders::error, new_socket, std::to_string(name)));
}

void DummyNetwork::disconnect(int port) {
    if (isConnected(port)) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(connectionsMutex_);
        const auto it = connections_.find(std::to_string(port));
        if (it != connections_.end()) {
            std::shared_ptr<DConnection> conn = it->second;
            conn->disconnectRequested_ = true;
            conn->socket_->close();
            printDebugMessage("Closed connection to " + conn->otherName_);
        }
        connections_.erase(std::to_string(port));
    }
}

NetworkMessage DummyNetwork::receiveMessageWithTypes(const std::vector<int>& types, int port) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(messagesMutex_);
    while (port == 0 || isConnected(port)) {
        if (port == 0) {
            if (messages_[0].size() > 0) {
                DMessageReceival mr = messages_[0][0];
                messages_[0].erase(messages_[0].begin());
                for (auto it = messages_[mr.message_.type_].begin();
                     it != messages_[mr.message_.type_].end(); it++) {
                    if ((it->message_.encodedData_ ==
                         mr.message_.encodedData_) &&
                        (it->sender_ == mr.sender_)) {
                        messages_[mr.message_.type_].erase(it);
                        lock.unlock();
                        return mr.message_;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                messagesConditionVariable_.wait(lock);
            }
        } else {
            for (auto type: types) {
                if (messages_[type].size() > 0) {
                    DMessageReceival mr = messages_[type][0];
                    messages_[type].erase(messages_[type].begin());
                    for (auto it = messages_[0].begin();
                         it != messages_[0].end(); it++) {
                        if ((it->message_.encodedData_ ==
                             mr.message_.encodedData_) &&
                            (it->sender_ == mr.sender_)) {
                            messages_[0].erase(it);
                            lock.unlock();
                            return mr.message_;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            messagesConditionVariable_.wait(lock);
        }
    }
    return {};
}

void DummyNetwork::shutdown() {
    shutdownRequested_ = true;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(connectionsMutex_);
    for (const auto& [key, value] : connections_) {
        value->disconnectRequested_ = true;
        value->socket_->close();
        printDebugMessage("Closed connection to " + value->otherName_);
    }
    connections_.clear();
}
```

I suspect the problem is with my use of the boost library, specifically my use of the io_service object, either a) not properly posting work to its queue or b) not properly executing stuff of the queue.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code.

Just a few things stand out immediately:

```
printDebugMessage("Accepted connection to port" + socket->remote_endpoint().port());
```

Makes no sense. You're adding an integer to a string literal. If you enable compiler warnings you will know when you write boo-boos like this. You have this correctly (albeit duplicated) in different parts of your code.

Much bigger:

```
char new_buffer[10000];
connection->socket_->async_read_some(asio::buffer(new_buffer),
                                     boost::bind(&DummyNetwork::handleRead, this, connection,
                                                 new_buffer, ph::error, ph::bytes_transferred));
```

This makes no sense either. `new_buffer` is a local variable. By definition, you won't be able to access it in `handleRead`. Also, it will cease to exist at the end of the enclosing scope. You have this error twice:

```
char buffer[10000];
socket->async_read_some( //
    asio::buffer(buffer),
    boost::bind(&DummyNetwork::handleHandshakeRead, this, socket, buffer, ph::error,
                ph::bytes_transferred));
```

The rest of the code is... very very complicated.

- I don't know why you update `isListening_`. Its value seems never useful.
- You basically never inspect any `error_code`. That's a recipe for unnecessary confusion
- You have all operations right on `DummyNetwork`. This means it's overloaded in responsibilities. It acts as a listener **and** as (multiple) connections. In that regard, we have to ask why you even have a separate `DConnection` type in the first place.
- `receiveMessagesWithTypes` smells like an 1980's select/poll loop. You're using Asio now, why bother?
- You have explicit thread synchronization (`messageConditionVariable_`, `messagesMutex_`). This too does not seem to match async IO using Asio well
- you resolve endpoints, but somehow only consider the first resolver result; prefer `asio::async_connect`
- you interpret the contents of the `buffer` received as if it were a valid nul-terminated string, ignoring `bytes_read`
- you have a data race in `shutdown` where you call `close()` under the `connectionsMutex`. However, the `connection` may be in use by other async completion handlers that do not take the same lock. You're probably much better off using strands - or recognizing that you have a single-thread per "network" instance, and posting the close to it. Also, consider `shutdown(...)` or `cancel()` instead of `close()`.
- you use `async_write_some` which does not guarantee to send the entire buffer. Prefer `asio::async_write`.
- Also, prefer scatter/gather instead of the manual encode/decode stuff you seem to have going on (not shown). At the very least it appears to be very inconsistent (the `type_` is bound to be duplicated in the member as well as in the `encode()` result - which I **hope** is not returning by value, because that would mean more lifetime-error-induced [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in `asio::buffer(msg.encode(), msg.encode().length())`).
- Speaking of which, never specify the size of the buffer if it only means you might get it wrong: `asio::buffer(msg.encode())`
- `isConnected` is a racy interface: by definition, the returned value becomes stale as soon as `connectionMutex_` is released. A more likely useful interface would take a `unique_lock` or assume the lock held by the caller.
- `send` only checks `shutdownRequested` iff `!isConnected(port)`. That seems wrong
  Here's a stab at fixing:

  ```
   void DummyNetwork::send(int port, NetworkMessage const& msg) {
       if (shutdownRequested_)
           printDebugMessage("Can't send. Shutdown.");
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex>  lock(connectionsMutex_);

       if (auto conn = connections_[std::to_string(port)]) {
           asio::async_write(*conn->socket_, asio::buffer(msg.encode()),
                             boost::bind(&DummyNetwork::handleWrite, this, ph::error, msg, conn->otherName_));
           printDebugMessage("Requested to write msg " + msg.encodedData_ + " to port " + std::to_string(port));
       } else {
           printDebugMessage("Can't send. Not connected to port " + std::to_string(port));
       }
   }
  ```

  Of course, now we notice here too `msg` is not life-time guaranteed until `async_write` completes... In fact in **every single** invocation of `send` you are passing a temporary `NetworkMessage`. Sigh. More lifetime errors.
- You have no provision to prevent the next `send` from happening before a previous `send` completed:

  ```
   netB.send(portA, NetworkMessage{2, "hello"});
   netB.send(portA, NetworkMessage{1, "hii"});
  ```

  This may violate the requirements [documented at `asio::async_write`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html):

  > *This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's `async_write_some` function, and is known as a composed operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write operations (such as async_write, the stream's `async_write_some` function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until this operation completes.*

  I am aware that you had `async_write_some` in your code, but that was in itself a mistake. You probably need the [wellknown outbound queue pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371%20outbox_)
- You bind some completion handlers to `connection`, some to `other_name`, some even to a raw `tcp::socket` instance. All of these probably should be members on `DConnection` instead and use `shared_from_this`.
- You have `async_read_some` which has the same problem as `async_write_some`: there is no guarantee it reads a "complete message". You probably need to add framing to your protocol, so you know definitively when a message is complete. Otherwise, you will incorrectly parse a partial message, which is confusing enough. However, you will also interpret the trailing data as a new message which will just lead to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) again because it doesn't start with a type, or, indeed, may not be long enough to even contain such header data.

Perhaps if you described what it was you want to achieve, I'd be able to help show how I'd implement that. Meanwhile here's my half-way review incorporating many of the above mentioned ideas:

**[(Un)live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb62e6923dbf4056)**

Mind you, I couldn't test the logic because the logic was unclear to begin with, and the provided implementation couldn't work (so I had no comparison). The code is merely provided to illustrate some of the points I made along the way.

### UPDATE

Complete alternative implementation

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69a694ad1961fca6)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace { // diagnostics tracing helpers
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;

    static auto timestamp() {
        static auto start = now();
        return (now() - start) / 1.ms;
    }

    static std::atomic_int tid_gen = 0;
    thread_local int       tid     = tid_gen++;
    std::mutex             console_mx;

    void trace(auto const&... args) {
        std::lock_guard lk(console_mx);
        std::cout << "T:" << std::setw(2) << tid << std::right << std::setw(10) << timestamp() << "ms ";
        (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
    }
} // namespace

namespace Network {
    namespace asio = boost::asio;
    namespace ph   = asio::placeholders;
    namespace bmi  = boost::multi_index;
    namespace s2   = boost::signals2;
    using duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;
    using asio::ip::tcp;
    using boost::system::error_code;
#ifdef VERBOSE
    using mutex_type = std::recursive_mutex;        // recursive only to allow locking inside trace function
    using cv_type    = std::condition_variable_any; // _any to allow recursive mutex
#else
    using mutex_type = std::mutex;
    using cv_type    = std::condition_variable;
#endif

    struct timeout_exception : std::runtime_error{
        timeout_exception() : std::runtime_error("timeout_exception") {}
    };

    struct Message {
        using NetInt32 = boost::endian::big_int32_t;

        Message(int type = -1, std::string payload = {}) : type_(type), payload_(std::move(payload)) {
            prepare_payload();
        }

        int                type() const { return type_; }
        std::string const& payload() const { return payload_; }
        void               prepare_payload() { payloadsize_ = payload_.size(); }

        asio::mutable_buffer prepare_payload_buffer() {
            payload_.resize(payloadsize_);
            return asio::buffer(payload_);
        }

        auto buffers() const {
            return std::array{
                asio::buffer(&type_, sizeof(type_)),
                asio::buffer(&payloadsize_, sizeof(payloadsize_)),
                asio::buffer(payload_),
            };
        }

        auto mutable_headers() {
            return std::array{
                asio::buffer(&type_, sizeof(type_)),
                asio::buffer(&payloadsize_, sizeof(payloadsize_)),
            };
        }

      private:
        NetInt32    type_;
        NetInt32    payloadsize_;
        std::string payload_;
    };

    struct Receipt {
        size_t      ordinal;
        Message     message_;
        std::string sender_;

        int type() const { return message_.type(); }
    };

    class Session;
    using SessionPtr = std::shared_ptr<Session>;

    class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
        int const id = []{ static int gen = 0; return ++gen; }();
        void trace(auto const&... args) const {
            ::trace("Session#", id, "\t", peerPort_, '/', quoted(peerName_), " ", args...);
        }

      public:
        Session(asio::any_io_executor ex) : socket_(ex) {}

        Session(tcp::socket s)
            : socket_(std::move(s))
            , peerPort_(socket_.remote_endpoint().port())
            , peerName_(std::to_string(peerPort_)) {}

        ~Session() { trace("Destructing"); }

        uint16_t           peerPort() const { return peerPort_; }
        std::string const& peerName() const { return peerName_; }

        s2::signal<void(SessionPtr const&)>                 when_established;
        s2::signal<void(SessionPtr const&, Message const&)> when_message;

      private:
#include <boost/asio/yield.hpp>
        template <typename Token> auto async_receive(Token&& token) {
            auto init = [this, coro = asio::coroutine{}](auto&& self, error_code ec = {},
                                                         size_t = {}) mutable {
                reenter(coro) {
                    yield asio::async_read(socket_, incoming_.mutable_headers(), std::move(self));

                    if (ec.failed())
                        return self.complete(ec, incoming_);

                    yield asio::async_read(socket_, incoming_.prepare_payload_buffer(), std::move(self));

                    trace("Received message payload ", quoted(incoming_.payload()), ", ", ec.message());
                    self.complete(ec, incoming_);
                }
            };
            return asio::async_compose<decltype(token), void(error_code, Message)>(init, token);
        }

        template <typename Token> auto async_connect_handshake(std::string ourName, Token&& token) {
            auto init = [=, this, coro = asio::coroutine{}] //
                (auto&& self, error_code ec = {}, tcp::endpoint = {}) mutable {
                    reenter(coro) {
                        yield socket_.async_connect({{}, peerPort_}, std::move(self));
                        if (ec.failed())
                            return self.complete(ec);

                        trace("Connected to ", socket_.remote_endpoint(), " ", ec.message());

                        do_send(Message{0, ourName});

                        self.complete(ec);
                    }
                };
            return asio::async_compose<decltype(token), void(error_code)>(init, token);
        }
#include <boost/asio/unyield.hpp>

      public:
        void startIncoming() {
            // not posting to strand because startXXXX() is always called as first & only operation
            assert(socket_.is_open());
            async_receive(
                boost::bind(&Session::on_incoming_handshake, shared_from_this(), ph::error, boost::placeholders::_2));
        }

        void startOutgoing(uint16_t port, std::string ourName) {
            // not posting to strand because startXXXX() is always called as first & only operation
            assert(!socket_.is_open());
            peerPort_ = port;
            peerName_ = std::to_string(port);
            async_connect_handshake(ourName,
                                    boost::bind(&Session::on_establish, shared_from_this(), ph::error));
        }

        void send(Message msg) {
            post(socket_.get_executor(),
                 [this, self = shared_from_this(), m = std::move(msg)]() mutable { do_send(std::move(m)); });
        }

        void shutdown() {
            post(socket_.get_executor(), [this, self = shared_from_this()]() mutable { do_shutdown(); });
        }

      private:
        // assumed on strand
        void do_receive_message() {
            async_receive(
                boost::bind(&Session::on_message, shared_from_this(), ph::error, boost::placeholders::_2));
        }

        void do_send(Message msg) {
            outbox_.push_back(std::move(msg));
            if (outbox_.size() == 1)
                do_write_loop();
        }

        void do_shutdown() {
            socket_.cancel(); // maybe close()?
        }

        void do_write_loop() {
            if (outbox_.empty())
                return;

            asio::async_write( //
                socket_, outbox_.front().buffers(),
                [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                    trace("write loop: ", n, " bytes, ", ec.message());
                    if (ec.failed())
                        return do_shutdown();

                    outbox_.pop_front();
                    do_write_loop();
                });
        }

        void on_incoming_handshake(error_code ec, Message msg) {
            trace(__FUNCTION__, ": ", ec.message());
            if (ec.failed())
                return do_shutdown();

            if (msg.type() != 0) {
                trace(__FUNCTION__, ": Invalid handshake message");
                return do_shutdown();
            }

            peerName_ = msg.payload();
            trace("Handshake ", quoted(peerName_), " on port ", peerPort_);

            on_establish(ec);
        }

        void on_establish(error_code ec) {
            trace(__FUNCTION__, ": ", ec.message());
            if (ec.failed())
                return do_shutdown();

            when_established(shared_from_this());
            do_receive_message();
        }

        void on_message(error_code ec, Message msg) {
            trace(__FUNCTION__, ": ", ec.message());
            if (ec.failed())
                return do_shutdown();

            when_message(shared_from_this(), msg);

            do_receive_message();
        }

        tcp::socket         socket_;
        uint16_t            peerPort_ = 0xFFFF;
        std::string         peerName_ = "(none)";
        // message exchange
        Message             incoming_;
        std::deque<Message> outbox_;
    };

    class Listener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Listener>{
        int const id = []{ static int gen = 0; return ++gen; }();
        void trace(auto const&... args) const {
            ::trace("Listener#", id, "\t", acceptor_.local_endpoint(), " ", args...);
        }

      public:
        Listener(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port) : acceptor_(ex, {{}, port}) {}

        void listen(std::function<void(SessionPtr const&)> when_established = {}) {
            trace("Listening at ", acceptor_.local_endpoint());
            doAccept(when_established);
        }

      private:
        void doAccept(std::function<void(SessionPtr const&)> when_established = {}) {
            acceptor_.async_accept( //
                make_strand(acceptor_.get_executor()),
                [=, this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
                    trace("on_accept: ", ec.message());
                    if (ec.failed())
                        return;

                    auto sess = std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(s));
                    if (when_established)
                        sess->when_established.connect(when_established);
                    sess->startIncoming();
                    doAccept(when_established);
                });
        }
        tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    };

    class Hub {
        int const id = []{ static int gen = 0; return ++gen; }();
        void trace(auto const&... args) const {
#ifdef VERBOSE
            auto nmsg = [&] { std::lock_guard lk(messages_mx_); return messages_.size(); }();
            auto nconn = [&] { std::lock_guard lk(connections_mx_); return connections_.size(); }();
            ::trace("Hub#", id, "\t", port_, " (messages_:", nmsg, ", connections_:", nconn, ") ", args...);
#else
            ::trace("Hub#", id, "\t", port_, " ", args...);
#endif
        }

        auto register_session() {
            return [this](SessionPtr sp) { // when_established
                if (!sp)
                    return;
                {
                    trace("Established connection to ", sp->peerPort(), " (", quoted(sp->peerName()), ")");
                    std::lock_guard lk(connections_mx_);
                    connections_.emplace(sp->peerName(), sp);
                }

                sp->when_established.disconnect_all_slots();

                sp->when_message.connect([this](SessionPtr const& sp, Message msg) {
                    trace("Received ", quoted(msg.payload()), " from ", sp->peerName());
                    std::lock_guard lk(messages_mx_);

                    messages_.push_back({message_id_sequence_++, msg, sp->peerName()});
                    messages_cv_.notify_all();
                });
            };
        }

      public:
        Hub(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port) : ex_(ex), port_(port) { trace("Created"); }

        void listen() {
            if (isListening_.exchange(true))
                return;

            std::make_shared<Listener>(ex_, port_)->listen(register_session());
        }

        void send(std::string peerName, Message msg) {
            if (shutdownRequested_) {
                trace("Can't send. Shutdown.");
                return;
            }

            if (auto conn = find_session(peerName))
                conn->send(std::move(msg));
            else
                trace("Can't send. No connection for ", quoted(peerName));
        }

        void connect(uint16_t port) {
            std::string name = std::to_string(port_);
            if (!isConnected(name)) {
                auto sess = std::make_shared<Session>(make_strand(ex_));
                sess->when_established.connect(register_session());
                sess->startOutgoing(port, std::move(name));
            }
        }

        // void disconnect(uint16_t port);
        Message receiveMessage(duration timeout) {
            std::unique_lock lk(messages_mx_);

            if (!messages_cv_.wait_for(lk, timeout, [&] { return !messages_.empty(); }))
                throw timeout_exception{};

            Receipt mr = std::move(messages_.front());
            messages_.pop_front();

            return std::move(mr.message_);
        }

        Message receiveMessageWithTypes(duration timeout, std::vector<int> const& types, uint16_t port) {
            std::string const name = std::to_string(port);
            if (port == 0)
                return receiveMessage(timeout);

            std::unique_lock lk(messages_mx_);

            auto& idx = messages_.get<perType>();

            do {
                for (auto t : types) {
                    if (auto r = idx.equal_range(t); r.first != r.second) {
                        Receipt mr = std::move(*r.first);
                        idx.erase(r.first);
                        return mr.message_;
                    }
                }
                if (std::cv_status::timeout == messages_cv_.wait_for(lk, timeout)) {
                    throw timeout_exception{};
                }
            } while (isConnected(name));

            throw std::runtime_error("Not connected");
        }

        void shutdown() {
            std::lock_guard lk(connections_mx_);
            for (auto const& [name, conn] : connections_) {
                conn->shutdown();
                trace("Closed connection to ", quoted(name));
            }
            connections_.clear();
        }

      private:
        asio::any_io_executor ex_;
        uint16_t              port_;
        std::unordered_map<std::string, SessionPtr> connections_;

        size_t message_id_sequence_ = 0;
        bmi::multi_index_container<
            Receipt,                          //
            bmi::indexed_by<bmi::sequenced<>, // general queue
                            bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<struct perType>,
                                                bmi::key<&Receipt::type, &Receipt::ordinal>> // per-type
                            >>
            messages_;

        SessionPtr find_session(std::string const& name) const {
            std::lock_guard lk(connections_mx_);

            auto it = connections_.find(name);
            return it != connections_.end() ? it->second : nullptr;
        }

        std::atomic<bool>  isListening_{false};
        std::atomic<bool>  shutdownRequested_{false};
        mutable mutex_type connections_mx_;
        mutable mutex_type messages_mx_;
        cv_type            messages_cv_;

        bool isConnected(std::string const& name) { return !!find_session(name); }
    };

} // namespace Network

#define CHECK(cond)                                                                                          \
    do {                                                                                                     \
        auto&& c = (cond);                                                                                   \
        trace("Check '" #cond "': ", std::boolalpha, c);                                                     \
    } while (false)

void DummyNetwork_Basic() {
    using namespace Network;
    asio::thread_pool ioc(1);

    constexpr uint16_t portA = 3000;
    constexpr uint16_t portB = 3001;

    Hub netA = Hub(ioc.get_executor(), portA);
    Hub netB = Hub(ioc.get_executor(), portB);

    netA.listen();
    netB.listen();

    // network portB connects to network portA
    netB.connect(portA);

    // sleep to give time for connection
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);

    // network portA sends message to network portB
    netA.send(std::to_string(portB), Message{1, "hi"});

    // network portB calls a blocking function to receive messages
    Message receivedOnN2_m1 = netB.receiveMessageWithTypes(1s, {1}, portA);

    bool result1 = receivedOnN2_m1.payload() == "hi";
    CHECK(result1);

    // network portB sends messages to network portA
    netB.send(std::to_string(portA), Message{2, "hello"});
    netB.send(std::to_string(portA), Message{1, "hii"});

    // network portA attempts to receive messages via blocking read
    Message receivedOnN1_m1 = netA.receiveMessageWithTypes(1s, {2}, portB);
    Message receivedOnN1_m2 = netA.receiveMessageWithTypes(1s, {1}, portB);

    // clean up
    netA.shutdown();
    netB.shutdown();

    bool result2 = receivedOnN1_m1.payload() == "hello";
    bool result3 = receivedOnN1_m2.payload() == "hii";
    CHECK(result2);
    CHECK(result3);

    if (result1 && result2 && result3) {
        trace("DummyNetwork_Basic Passed");
    } else {
        trace("DummyNetwork_Basic Passed");
    }
}

int main() { //
    DummyNetwork_Basic();
}
```

Prints

```
g++ -std=c++2b -Ofast -Wall -pedantic main.cpp -pthread && ./a.out
T: 0  0.001854ms Hub#1  3000 Created
T: 0  0.076385ms Hub#2  3001 Created
T: 0  0.171003ms Listener#1 0.0.0.0:3000 Listening at 0.0.0.0:3000
T: 0  0.266008ms Listener#2 0.0.0.0:3001 Listening at 0.0.0.0:3001
T: 1   0.52161ms Listener#1 0.0.0.0:3000 on_accept: Success
T: 1  0.640365ms Session#1  3000/"3000" Connected to 127.0.0.1:3000 Success
T: 1  0.714466ms Session#1  3000/"3000" on_establish: Success
T: 1  0.730936ms Hub#2  3001 Established connection to 3000 ("3000")
T: 1  0.766172ms Session#1  3000/"3000" write loop: 12 bytes, Success
T: 1  0.792727ms Session#2  34546/"34546" Received message payload "3001", Success
T: 1  0.804801ms Session#2  34546/"34546" on_incoming_handshake: Success
T: 1  0.814638ms Session#2  34546/"3001" Handshake "3001" on port 34546
T: 1  0.825382ms Session#2  34546/"3001" on_establish: Success
T: 1  0.834955ms Hub#1  3000 Established connection to 34546 ("3001")
T: 1   3000.73ms Session#2  34546/"3001" write loop: 10 bytes, Success
T: 1   3000.82ms Session#1  3000/"3000" Received message payload "hi", Success
T: 1   3000.83ms Session#1  3000/"3000" on_message: Success
T: 1   3000.85ms Hub#2  3001 Received "hi" from 3000
T: 0   3000.89ms Check 'result1': true
T: 1   3000.98ms Session#1  3000/"3000" write loop: 13 bytes, Success
T: 1   3001.01ms Session#2  34546/"3001" Received message payload "hello", Success
T: 1   3001.02ms Session#2  34546/"3001" on_message: Success
T: 1   3001.03ms Hub#1  3000 Received "hello" from 3001
T: 1   3001.06ms Session#1  3000/"3000" write loop: 11 bytes, Success
T: 1   3001.08ms Session#2  34546/"3001" Received message payload "hii", Success
T: 1   3001.09ms Session#2  34546/"3001" on_message: Success
T: 1    3001.1ms Hub#1  3000 Received "hii" from 3001
T: 0   3001.13ms Hub#1  3000 Closed connection to "3001"
T: 0   3001.16ms Hub#2  3001 Closed connection to "3000"
T: 0   3001.17ms Check 'result2': true
T: 0   3001.19ms Check 'result3': true
T: 0    3001.2ms DummyNetwork_Basic Passed
T: 1   3001.22ms Session#2  34546/"3001" on_message: Operation canceled
T: 1   3001.24ms Session#2  34546/"3001" Destructing
T: 0   3001.35ms Session#1  3000/"3000" Destructing
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. I am aware of most of the malpractices I committed (checking for error cases, types, buffer misuses etc). But, I did not fix these out of laziness because the task is just a personal project to understand boost. My main problem with the code was not these things, but the fact that no async calls occur. With all the suggestions you had, unfortunately, this problem still occurs. When implemented, the program still does no connecting, writing, reading, etc.

Comment: I'm all for looking at fixes, if only I understood better what the purpose was. Or, even just the wire protocol. I can invent my own and use it to show you things, but it will naturally not have the issue(s) you're having. I do think a number of the ones you didn't mention do contribute to your issue (mainly the lack of framing).

Comment: Using a lot of imagination I made my take on it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69a694ad1961fca6 - I think that should be close to what you meant. It is only using a single IO thread and correctly shuts down. I also opted for a timeout on the waits otherwise it's way too easy to get deadlocks. You should consider signaling the condition variable on connection mutations as well, and storing weak pointers instead of shared pointers etc.